# Ruby minitest LoadError

Tags: ruby, minitest

I was doing a tutorial on a Terminal and recommended to use gem minitest.

I followed an instruction but didn't run in the exact way.

works/ruby-book/test/rgb_test.rb

```
require 'minitest/ autorun'  
require './lib/ rgb'  

class RgbTest <Minitest:: Test    
  def test_ to_ hex 
    assert_ equal '#000000', to_ hex( 0, 0, 0)    
  end  
end
```

works/ruby-book/lib/rgb.rb

```
def to_hex(r, g, b)
  '#000000'
end
```

when I run `$ ruby test/rgb_test.rb` under ruby-book directory, I got

```
    /Users/hostname/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require': cannot load such file -- .lib/rgb (LoadError)   
 from/Users/hostname/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
        from test/rgb_test.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

What is happening here and how can I fix this problem?

My minitest version is 5.10.0.

Comment: The path should be "../../lib/rgb" and you should use require_relative.

Comment: thank you. I changed my code` 'require './lib/rgb'` to `require_relative '../../lib/rgb' ` and I got another LoadError again.

Comment: Ups, I meant ../lib/rgb, one directory under, since you're just right on test/.